# Spotify API - Retrieving Valid Access Token in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, spotify

Here is the documentation for the Spotify API (I'm using the Implicit Grant Flow): https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow

I'm trying to write a script in Google Sheets. I'm focussing on the basic setup, but I cannot seem to get the access token working.

> SOLVED:
>
> I'm currently receiving the following error (it seems like my
>   parameters for my fetch method aren't set properly):
>
> *"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant_type must be client_credentials, authorization_code or refresh_token"*
>
> SOLUTION:
>
> The grant_type must be listed as a payload according to the Google
>   Scripts method UrlFetchApp.fetch (see updated code below)

--

> SOLVED:
>
> As you can see below I'm using the 'get' method when trying to get the
>   token (despite the documentation specifying 'post') because the post
>   method consistently returns a 405 error. I think this is the step I'm
>   screwing up on. I'm assuming that I'm not supposed to be using the
>   csrf_token as the access token.
>
> SOLUTION:
>
> https://accounts.spotify.com/token should have been
>   https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token

Updated working code below:

```
  var fetchParams = {
    'method':'post',
    'payload':{'grant_type':'client_credentials'},
    'headers':{'Authorization':authorization},
    'muteHttpExceptions':true
  }

  var replaceResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', fetchParams);

  var regExp = /access_token(.*?):/;

  var contentText = replaceResponse.getContentText();
  var access_token = contentText.slice(contentText.search('access_token')+15,contentText.search(',')-1);

  var requestOptions = {
    'headers':{'Authorization':'Bearer '+access_token},
    'muteHttpExceptions':true
  }

  var finalResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4dhARBZ8YLvm8oRDnCIeXr', requestOptions);
```

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node/issues/86). You encountered that error maybe because the access token that you have provided has expired. When this happens, you need to obtain a new access token. You may need to recheck the authorization flows explained on [Spotify's developer site](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/).

Comment: I don't think that the token could expire, my code runs in less than 10 seconds. The client_id and client_secret don't change (and I've checked my dev dashboard on Spotify for any changes).

I'm fetching the token (csrf_token) and using it pretty much immediately.

Comment: Can we ask you about the error messages when you requested with POST method?

Comment: @Tanaike This is the ContentText: {"error":"server_error","error_description":"Unexpected status: 405"}

Comment: Thank you for replying. The error is from ``replaceResponse``?

Comment: @Tanaike that is correct. I'm running into that error while creating the replaceResponser variable.

Comment: From the URL of your question, it seems that the request for retrieving access token is POST request. In your script, when ``'method':'get'`` of ``fetchParams`` is modified to ``'method':'post'``, such error is returned. Is my understanding correct? And, the endpoint for retrieving access token is ``https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token`` in the document. But your script is ``https://accounts.spotify.com/token``. How about this differences?

Comment: @Tanaike wow- I had changed the URL since I was using a different auth flow previously, but I made a very simple and stupid mistake to not copy and paste. Thank you. If you want to post your answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: As a follow up, I am still receiving the following error:
"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant_type must be client_credentials, authorization_code or refresh_token"

I'm wondering if my fetchParams may be setup incorrectly. I have not used the fetch method in the past and not sure what should be in the header or the body, etc. Do you have any suggestions? (otherwise I can post a new question)

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I'm glad a part of your issue was solved. But it seems that your issue is left yet. So can you update your this question using the response you got now? I think that your question is to use Spotify APIs by retrieving access token. So I would like to solve about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your script for retrieving access token by following `curl -X "POST" -H "Authorization: Basic ZjM4ZjAw...WY0MzE=" -d grant_type=client_credentials https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token` of the document. Can you please try this modified script?

```
var authorization = "Basic "+ Utilities.base64Encode('<client_id>:<client_secret>');
var fetchParams = {
  method: 'post', // Modified
  payload: {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}, // Modified
  headers: {'Authorization': authorization},
  muteHttpExceptions: true
}
var replaceResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", fetchParams); // Modified
Logger.log(replaceResponse.getContentText())
```

#### Reference :

- [Client Credentials Flow](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow)

If the response message was changed, please tell me.

Comment: You beat me to it! Just updated my code the same way and tested that it was fully working. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad your issue was completely solved. I could also study from your question. Thank you, too.