# Spotify API User Authorization from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, spotify

I would like to manipulate my Spotify playlists from a Google Apps script. I managed so far to access the Spotify API using a "client credentials" token. This way, I can search for songs and retrieve all kinds of audio analysis.

Now, in order to manipulate my playlists, I need to obtain another kind of access, involving OAuth2 and the notion of a redirect url.

I can find some examples on how to do this for e.g. Python programs running on my own PC, but not how to handle it from a Google Apps script.

Can anyone give some pointers or even better, some sample code?

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459496/spotify-api-retrieving-valid-access-token-in-google-apps-scripts/50499044#50499044